# Too many positional options mongoimport Error

Tags: mongodb, csv

I have a comma separated csv file with data for following fields: `Train_ID ,Train_Number, Train_name`

I wrote the following query to import the data from csv to mongodb:

```
mongoimport --db test --collection csvimporting --type csv --file "C:/Darshil Babel/Desktop/sample_data.csv" --fields Train_ID,Train_Number,Train_Name
```

It is giving following error:

```
Error parsing command line: too many positional options
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post some section of **sample_data.csv**

Comment: That command works fine for me with a suitable filename that also has a space in it. Can you double check that that is exactly the command you put into your terminal?